# "The namespace 'console' already contains a definition for 'Circle'"

Tags: c#, class, methods, system, geometry

I'm working on some code for a school project, where we are to have a class defining a circle and a method from which it draws, my code so far returns "The namespace 'console' already contains a definition for 'Circle' here is the code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace console
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.Write("What is the circle’s radius: ");
            double radius = Convert.ToDouble(Console.ReadLine());
            Circle ans = new Circle(radius);


            Console.WriteLine("The area of the circle is " + ans.getArea);
            Console.WriteLine("The Diameter of the circle is " + ans.getDiameter);
            Console.WriteLine("The Circumference of the circle is " + ans.getCircumference);

            Console.Write("Enter any character to quit program. ");
            double stop = Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

That's the method and the class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace console
{
    class Circle
    {

 public double radius;
            public const double PI = 3.14159;
            public Circle(double r)
            {
            radius = r;
        }
        public Circle()
        {
            radius = 0.0;
        }

        public double getDiameter
        {
            get
            {
                return radius * 2;
            }

        }


        public double getArea
        {
            get
            {
                return PI * radius * radius;
            }

        }
        public double getCircumference
        {
            get
            {
                return 2 * PI * radius;
            }

        }
        // property Radius 
        public double Radius
        {
            get
            {
                return radius;
            }

            set
            {
                // ensure non-negative radius value 
                if (value >= 0)
                    radius = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

One final question for this, now that I have the working code, the set and get are supposed to not allow negative input. However, when this is run, negative input still returns results, what am I missing that is causing the negative values to still be calculated?

Comment: Maybe you have two classes with the same name `Circle`?

Comment: You have two classes named Circle within the same namespace. Call the tester CircleTester or something..

Comment: Why did you name both classes `Circle`? Call the one with the `Main` method `Program` or something, and the problem is gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is quite specific. You've declared two classes with the same name `Circle` in the same namespace. You can't do that. The compiler needs to be able to distinguish between the two classes, how can it do that if they have the same name?

I would recommend changing the name of the class that contains your Main entry point to something more appropriate, such as `Program`.

Also, as good practice you should stick to generally accepted naming conventions and name your namespace `Console`, rather than `console`.

Comment: See, I have tried that, the returned errors from changing that is that '*blank* does not exist in the current context"

Comment: What is 'blank'? That doesn't appear in your code. Is that a runtime or a compile time error?

Comment: I was using that to generalize sorry, it returns that multiple times for PI and radius.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really follow. If you rename the class with Main to Program, does it compile? That's the first step. If not are both classes you show the code for in the same project (i.e. a Console project)?  If the project does compile, and the error is a runtime error the debugger (or the exception help box in Visual Studio) should tell you what line the exception occurs at, which line is this?

Comment: Ah wait, I see. You've defined PI and radius in the Program class, so they are not accessible in the Circle class. Move the PI constant and radius field into the Circle class... that should move things on!  The error is confusing as your code is very close to working, if you made both your Circle classes partial it may well work. But that's not the right way to fix the problem. You need to correctly separate the Circle class with it's Circle based values/methods from your Main program.

Comment: By changing the classes to different names, I went from having one error to 10 which all state that within my class for the circle, "The name 'PI' does not exist in the current context" this error also happens for 'radius' I cannot get it to compile for these errors. And yes, both these codes are in the same project

Comment: Thank you so much, just a silly minor mistake but its all working now!

Comment: Good, making those mistakes is the only way to learn to program.  Keep up the good work.

Comment: Another question, if I were looking to make the program prompt whether the user wanted to make another calculation or not. while not allowing negative integers, how would I go about that?

I have been trying a do loop on the program portion but just keep getting a 'does not exist in current context error'

Comment: You should be able to wrap the entire contents of Main in a loop. Then at the end where you do Console.Read(), look at the character they typed. If it is a 'Y' then continue with the loop, otherwise break out.  I would use a while loop. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2aeyhxcd.aspx

Answer (score 4):

(Compiler output messages are your friends: do learn to understand them.)

You cannot have two classes named the same thing in the same namespace.

`Circle` appears twice in the `console` namespace.

Just rename one of them. If I were you I'd change the first one as it's not really modelling a circle. The second class is however.

Comment: See, I have tried that, the returned errors from changing that is that 'blank does not exist in the current context"

That's why I had it so that both classes were named the same.

Comment: If Circle is not found after changing the class with Main to Program, they aren't in the same project. Because they're in the same namespace, you don't even need a using. The files just both have to be in the project and preferably the same folder...